# UIMenuController is deprecated. Use UIEditMenuInteraction instead. iOS 16

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios16

I am using UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification in my app. but in iOS16 UIMenuController is deprecated.

I want to check when menu is open but in UIEditMenuInteraction class no Notification is available.

In webview I need to show custom menu not default menu.

Comment: There is no notification, but delegate methods.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: need to hide default context menu and show custom menu which is having only 2 options

Comment: Check this answer, maybe it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712955/using-uieditmenuinteraction-with-uitextview

Answer (score 1):

**Use webView.uiDelegate = self, it will notify for iOS 16. and keep the UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification for lower version.**

```
 @available(iOS 16.0, *)
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, willPresentEditMenuWithAnimator animator: UIEditMenuInteractionAnimating) {
    print("will present")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

this is code to remove default context menu

- (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id)builder

this is default method to get all menu items

[builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuShare];

use this code to remove menu items