# How to get UIMenuController position on iOS 16?

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller

On WKWebView, when users click an menu item, `menuFrame` can be retrieved from the following code on iOS 13:

```
let menuFrame = UIMenuController.shared.menuFrame
```

Although UIMenuController is deprecated on iOS 16, the menu can be showed up, but menuFrame returns `zero`.

What's the correct way to get a menu position?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIEditMenuInteraction instead of UIMenuController. This link might be useful to you. [UIMenuController is deprecated. Use UIEditMenuInteraction instead. iOS 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631526/uimenucontroller-is-deprecated-use-uieditmenuinteraction-instead-ios-16)